# Rails proper way to do multiple relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

A `User` model has many `notifications`, and many `sent_notifications`.

A `Notification` model has a `recipient_id` and a `creator_id`.

I tried to model these relationships like so:

**User.rb**

```
has_many :notifications, foreign_key: "recipient_id"
has_many :sent_notifications, foreign_key: "creator_id", class_name: "Notification"
```

**Notification.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
```

My **migration** looks like this:

```
class CreateNotifications < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :notifications do |t|
      t.integer :recipient_id
      t.integer :creator_id
      t.integer :video_id
      t.string :message

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

However, when I try to access the `creator` property on a Notification object, I get:

```
undefined method `creator' for #<Notification:0x007ff4ddf514d0>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Notification.rb** should be like this:

```
belongs_to :creator,   class_name: 'User'
belongs_to :recipient, class_name: 'User'
```

Comment: Though it should be `belongs_to` not `belong_to`.

Comment: D'oh! Fixed my answer.

Comment: I would also advise the new syntax, as used in the question -- `class_name: 'User'`, from what I can remember, this works, too: `class_name: User`

Comment: Oops. Just came from a question on Rails 3.2 where I was assuming ruby 1.9 or lower.